# I am entering birthdate inside edittext using datepicker. How to catch this?

Tags: android, datepicker, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getDate with Jquery Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562986/getdate-with-jquery-datepicker)

I have a registration page inside that I have birthdate box.
I am entering birthdate inside edittext using datepicker. How to catch this and put into web server. Do I need to parse to get integer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get reference to your EditText and use getText() method to get the text and 
on How to put into web server,

This can be one of the way.
Check this,
[Android (Java) Simple Send and receive with Server - Fast Setup Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983761/android-java-simple-send-and-recieve-with-server-fast-setup-challenge)

Comment: i did in that way i used    m1PickDate=Integer.parseInt(mPickDate.getText().toString()); but after doing this am getting error                                unable to parse '1-2-2006 ' as integer

Comment: Ya, Why do you want integer of the date !Let it be string , or use simpleDateFormat to store string in Date object.

Comment: how to use simpleDateFormat can you explain it or any code ???

Comment: simple example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/string-to-date-time-object-in-android , detailed description http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following, whereby you can get the various components (day, month and year) as integers

```
final DatePicker datePick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.proposeDate);

int day = datePick.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datePick.getMonth();
int year = datePick.getYear();
```

Comment: but i have not build any xml for this date i have used datepicker its working fine but when i enter the birthdate in edittext and run in logcat i get the response  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2/1/2006 "            my questin is how to parse it

Comment: You can easily use a DatePicker instead of the editbox. The values will be more manageable (For the EditBox, you will surely have to write a parser excluding the /)                                    <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/proposeDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
   />