# How to get date, month, year in jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this sample code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
      inline: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = dateText.getUTCMonth();
            var day = dateText.getUTCDate();
            var year = dateText.getUTCFullYear();
            alert(day+month+year);
     } 
    });
});
```

When I run the code, there is an error. How to get this `(date, month, year)`?

Comment: Might be similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562986/getdate-with-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use method **[getDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)**:

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
    inline: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
            day  = date.getDate(),  
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
            year =  date.getFullYear();
        alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VnbxH/)**

Comment: why did you + 1 in date.getMonth() + 1? can you expalin? thanks

Comment: month is 0..11, and need to  be translated to 1..12

Comment: Good work @Eli, I am searching this solution for last 15 minutes. It really helps me. But i have one confusion here day, month, year doesn't have a type. what't the type of that variables.

Answer (score 12):

Hi you can try viewing this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgL5p/).

I used this code:

```
var day = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();  
var month = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();  
var year = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getYear();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Now in 2015 the `getYear()` method is deprecated. Use `getFullYear()` instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

Answer (score 5):

Use the javascript Date object.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
      inline: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = new Date(dateText);
            // change date.GetDay() to date.GetDate()
            alert(date.getDate() + date.getMonth() + date.getFullYear());
     } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what about that simple way)

```
$(document).ready ->
 $('#datepicker').datepicker( dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  onSelect: (dateStr) ->
    alert dateStr # yy-mm-dd
    #OR
    alert $("#datepicker").val(); # yy-mm-dd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#date").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;
```

The month on the datepicker is 0 based (0-11), so add 1 to get the month as it appears in the date.