# how i will extract month and year from month year picker,i am using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want month and year seperate from this month/year picker. i tried this.

i want to insert month and year to database,for that i want it seperate.i am using codeigniter frame work

```
var month= $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        window.write(' month');
```

its not working.

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">-->
<script src="../monthyear/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<label for="monthYearPicker">Date :</label>
<div class="monthYearPicker" name="myDate" ></div>
<!--<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />-->
     <script>  
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy'
        }).focus(function () {
            var thisCalendar = $(this);
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function () {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
   visibility:hidden;
}</style>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Its not working" ?

Comment: sir how will i get month  by post method?

Comment: update your question with actual problem that you are facing

Comment: for example:if its displaying(pageonload) JULY/2015,I  want month July and year 2015;

Comment: Check this : [similar datepicker question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186386/how-to-get-date-month-year-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Use onClose() method of datepicker.

```
onClose: function(dateText) { 
           dateVariable = dateText;
           if(dateVariable != null && dateVariable != ""){
                var arr = dateVariable.split(' ');
                $('#month').val(arr[0]);
                $('#year').val(arr[1]);
           }
```

**EXAMPLE :** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahajanankur/zmokhdtc/)

I hope this will solve your problem.