# get day,month,year values in jquery datepicker on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I get the values of jquery datepicker after the user click the button. 
I found this [How to get date, month, year in jQuery UI datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186386/how-to-get-date-month-year-in-jquery-ui-datepicker) but I need it to get done when the user click the button, not on the event when the user selected a date.

CODE:

```
     //FOR DATE PICKER
    $(function () {

     $('.dateRange').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1940: +nn"
          });
      });
      //When the button is click get the values of selected month,date,year
            function testDateRange() {

                 var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                 alert(date);

              }
```

I tried this

```
    var x = $('#MainContent_startDate').val();
```

it outputs e.g. 2/23/2016 but what I needed output is

```
     Month: 2
     Date: 23
     Year: 2016
```

Comment: just put the code in click button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var dt = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
 var date = dt.getDate();
 var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
 var year= dt.getFullYear();
```

Use the above 3 variables to print or use in your code.

Comment: hi, this is the error : Cannot read property 'getDate' of null

Comment: It means the variable "dt" gets null value. May be this happened if there was no date selected in the datepicker. I checked this code in your sample jsFiddle and it works. Make sure the variable dt gets a date value before fetching the date,month,year values from it.

Comment: I have selected a value before clicking the button, can you show the fiddle?

Comment: I'm using asp.net button, I call the js from code behind.

Comment: Anyhow as per your question, if you are getting a full date value on this line- var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');   Then you can obviously take date,month,year from that value as I explained in my answer. I have just updated your jsFiddle code to make it easy to understand. 
If you explain me exactly what is the problem to get it done because of the asp.net button, I can try to help you out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104231/discussion-between-vinothkumar-and-francis-saul).

Comment: I am now using html button and it works as expected. I just wonder why it can't be done using asp.net button even though I call the same js function.

Comment: The reasons could be, you have not marked the js function in a right way in C# code, or the id of the date picker control wasn't given correctly, you might tried using $(this) which will not work when you call from C# code. There could be several reasons behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var date = $(datepickerid).datepicker("getDate")
```

on button click event function.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb26pz52/)

Comment: it returns null , 
this is my code  var x = $('#MainContent_startDate').datepicker("getDate");
                  alert(x);

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that ur button id is '`btn`' Try this:

```
function testDateRange()             
{
 dt = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

 var mon='Month: '+ (dt.getMonth()+1) +' \nYear: '+ dt.getFullYear() + ' \nDay: ' + dt.getDate();

alert (mon);

}


 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn").click(
            function () {
                myDate();
            }            
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this :)

```
 var TestVar= $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

     var Date = TestVar.getDate();

     var Month = TestVar.getMonth();

     var Year= TestVar.getFullYear();
```

Comment: thank you friend, have a look at the above answer, same as yours :-)