# How to get date month and day in separate variable from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to get date day and month into separate variable and then place that variable into a `div` tag. Tell me where I need to change the code for that purpose.

```
$('.from_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    onSelect: function(){
      var selected = $(this).val();
      alert(selected);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What you are getting as 'selected'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get date, month, year in jquery ui datepicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186386/how-to-get-date-month-year-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

Parse your `selected` variable:

```
var
  selected = '2016-03-26';
  selectedToArray = selected.split('-'),
  year = selectedToArray[0], // 2016
  month = selectedToArray[1], // 03
  day = selectedToArray[2]; // 26
```

The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings. You can read more about this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Update:

```
$('.from_date').datepicker(
  { 
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    onSelect: function() { 

      var 
        selected = $(this).val(),
        selectedToArray = selected.split('-'),
        year = selectedToArray[0],
        month = selectedToArray[1],
        day = selectedToArray[2];

      $('#some_div_for_year').text(year);
      $('#some_div_for_month').text(month);

    } 
  }
);
```

Comment: $('.from_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
        onSelect: function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        alert(selected);
        }
    });
 where to place your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the javascript method "[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)"

```
var rawValue = '90-03-31';
var year = rawValue.split('-')[0]; // returns "90"
var month = rawValue.split('-')[1]; // returns "03"
var day = rawValue.split('-')[2]; // returns "31"
```

Answer (score 0):

parse date

```
$('.from_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", onSelect: function(){ 

       var selected = $(this).val(), 
       selectedArray = selected.split('-'),
       year = selectedArray [0],
       month = selectedArray [1],
       day = selectedArray [2];
} 
}); });
```