# Jquery datepicker. How I can get year from Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-plugins

Hi I have function but she does not work. I use jquery datepicker. I think problem in my datepicker does not work. How I can fix my function for get full year?    For me important in function get year.

```
function GetBirthDate() {
            var flatpickr = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                "altField": "#startDate",
                "dateFormat": "d M y",
                "altFormat": "Y-m-d",
                "changeMonth": true,
                "changeYear": true
            });

            let tdate = new Date(flatpickr);
            
            let yyyy = tdate.getFullYear();
            let currentDate = yyyy;
            return currentDate;
           
        };
```

I try fix but difficult understand how inside function get year:

```
function GetBirthDate() {
            var flatpickr = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
                inline: true,
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                        day = date.getDate(),
                        month = date.getMonth() + 1,
                        year = date.getFullYear();
                
                }
            });
            //let tdate = new Date(flatpickr);
            
            **let yyyy = flatpickr.getFullYear();
            let currentDate = year;**
            return currentDate;
         
        };
```

This datepicker does not work for me

```
var datepicker3jk = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            closeText: "Đóng",
            prevText: "Trước",
            nextText: "Sau",
            currentText: "Hôm nay",
            monthNames: ["Tháng một", "Tháng hai", "Tháng ba", "Tháng tư", "Tháng năm", "Tháng sáu", "Tháng bảy", "Tháng tám", "Tháng chín", "Tháng mười", "Tháng mười một", "Tháng mười hai"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Một", "Hai", "Ba", "Bốn", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy", "Tám", "Chín", "Mười", "Mười một", "Mười hai"],
            dayNames: ["Chủ nhật", "Thứ hai", "Thứ ba", "Thứ tư", "Thứ năm", "Thứ sáu", "Thứ bảy"],
 

   dayNamesShort: ["CN", "Hai", "Ba", "Tư", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy"],
    dayNamesMin: ["CN", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7"],
    weekHeader: "Tuần",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
            day = date.getDate(),
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            year = date.getFullYear(),
    },
});
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16186507/9038475) might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get date, month, year in jQuery UI datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186386/how-to-get-date-month-year-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: Not stil get 1 april 2010 even after select

Comment: Because you don't have an `onSelect` property, when creating the datepicker.

Comment: How I can do it?

Comment: I last time I flatpickr and this function work very correct. I need get full year. For after I can use it for count.

Comment: The same way as it is shown in the link, which I provided.

Comment: How I can get full year inside this function?

Comment: From this function I need back  full year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var flatpickr;
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-m-d",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-m-d", dateText);
      flatpickr = dt.getFullYear();
      console.log("Birth Year: " + flatpickr);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Birth Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

This page shows:

> **$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )**

> Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.

This can be used with `onSelect` to convert the Date Text into a Date Object.