# how to get the date from datepicker in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this snippet to display dates using datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
      }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
      }
    });

    $('#txtFrom').on("click", function(){
      alert($(this).getDate());
    });
});
```

Now I wanna be able to store each date in a variable and display and alert after choosing and clicking in the input submit button.
Please help

Note: In the snippet I actually tried but it didn't work.

[Hope you can help from the entire code here](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gmyoWM?editors=1111)

Comment: You are using `onSelect` event in which you are getting the selected date, so persist it. Whats the problem?

Comment: maybe a dup! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562986/getdate-with-jquery-datepicker

Comment: @Satpal. Hope you don't mind running the snippet to see what I am trying and that I can alert the date.

Comment: Thanks it works. Mind explaining what exactly was wrong in my snippet?

Comment: You attached click with `$('#txtFrom').on("click"`, where as I did `$('.submit-here').click(function() {` and note `txtToDate = selected;`

Comment: Appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

You can try on button click event:

```
$('#txtFrom').on("click", function(){
      alert($("#txtFrom").val());
      alert($("#txtTo").val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want as a Date Object use:

```
$('#txtFrom').datepicker( 'getDate' )
```